# filectime возвращает не правильное время

Tags: php, php7

Нужно получить дату и время создания документа. 
Код:

```
echo (date("F d Y H:i:s.",filectime($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/www/bitrix/import_1c/temp/ex.xlsx")));
```

Результат выполнения PHP:

```
May 24 2018 09:58:43.
```

Консоль:

[root@master1 shared]# ls -l

```
total 24
-rwxr--r-- 1 vrt-sql$ компьютеры домена 23232 May 24 09:00 ex.xlsx
```

Документ реально создан в 9.00 . Важно получить именно дату создания. Но echo выводит не понятное время.
Подскажите что не так и как быть?

Comment: filectime возвращает время последнего изменения файла, или FALSE в случае возникновения ошибки. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filectime.php

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer да я понимаю . Если файл не изменяется  , то фактически получим дату создания. Так как получить дату создания файла?

Comment: import.log и ex.xlsx этож вроде не один и тот же файл

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer прошу прощения! Я ошибся в описании 
`/bitrix/www/bitrix/import_1c/temp/ex.xlsx `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filectime
```

Возвращает время изменения индексного дескриптора (inode) файла. Например он изменяется при смене прав доступа к файлу.

```
filemtime
```

Данная функция возвращает время последней записи блоков файла, иначе говоря, изменения содержания файла.

`ls -l` выводит время последней записи блоков файла.

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема была в смене прав доступа